How to validate an enum in Django using serializers
I'm using serializers to validate my Post data.  How can I validate an Enum?
I have a class like this:
class DataTypeEnum(StrEnum):
    FLOAT = 'float'
    INTEGER = 'integer'
    BOOLEAN = 'boolean'

And my Post input contains
{
...
  "value" : <datatype>
...
}

where value should have the values of float, integer or boolean

Django not recommend to use Enum directly, more there:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types
But you can:
class DataTypeEnum(StrEnum):
    FLOAT = 'float'
    INTEGER = 'integer'
    BOOLEAN = 'boolean'

class DataTypeForm(Form):
    value = ChoiceField(choices=((dt.value, dt.name) for dt in DataTypeEnum), required=True)

    def clean_value(self):
        return DataTypeEnum(self.cleaned_data['value'])

clean_value you need to transform plain text in one of enum items.
